# Java program calculates incorrectly for certain data set but correctly for other data set

Tags: java, eclipse, date-arithmetic

I am writing a very simple program in which the user is trying to find out if he alters the diameter of a pancake (both new and old diameters are user inputted), given the quantity (user inputted), how many pancakes with the new diameter he can make. Now my calculation works with the test data: 10 old Diameter, 8 old Quantity, 4 new diameter. This results in 50 new pancakes which is correct, but when i enter 5 old Diameter, 10 old Quantity, 10 new diameter. This results in 1.59999 new pancakes which is incorrect, the answer should be 2.5. Here is my code, any help would be appreciated:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pancakes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int diameterOld = 0;                                                    // used to save diameter of original pancakes
        int quantityOld = 0;                                                    // used to save quantity of original pancakes
        int diameterNew = 0;                                                    // used to save diameter of new pancakes
        double quantityNew = 0;                                                 // used to save quantity of new pancakes
        double areaNew = 0;                                                     // used to store area of new pancakes 
        double areaOld = 0;                                                     // used to store area of original pancakes
        double totalSurfaceArea = 0;                                            // total amount of batter used

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                                 // allows keyboard input

        System.out.println ("Mohammad's java Pancakes");                        
        System.out.print ("Diameter of original pancakes (inches): ");          // Prints statement asking for diameter of original pancakes
        diameterOld = input.nextInt();                                          // saves input into diameterOld
        System.out.print ("Quantity of original pancakes: ");                   // Prints statement asking for quantity of original pancakes
        quantityOld = input.nextInt();                                          // saves input into quantityOld
        System.out.print ("Diameter of new pancakes (inches): ");               // Prints statement asking for diameter of new pancakes
        diameterNew = input.nextInt();                                          // saves input into diameterNew

        areaOld = ((diameterOld/2)*(diameterOld/2)*Math.PI);                    // calculates area of original pancakes
        totalSurfaceArea = (areaOld * quantityOld);                             // calculates total amount of batter needed
        areaNew = ((diameterNew/2)*(diameterNew/2)*Math.PI);                    // calculates area of new pancakes
        quantityNew = (totalSurfaceArea/areaNew);                               // calculates quantity of new pancakes

        System.out.println ("Quantity of new pancakes: " + quantityNew);        // Prints statement stating quantity of new pancakes and amount of new pancakes

        input.close();                                                          // Closes scanner input
    }

}
```

Comment: Confused... wouldn't 5 old Diameter, 10 old Quantity, 5 new diameter = 0 new pancakes?

Comment: I only get 1.59999999 if I enter 5, 10, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide `(diameterOld/2)` and likewise expressions, you are dividing two integers, thus the result will be an integer. So if `diameterOld` is equal to 5, `(diameterOld/2)` doesn't give `2.5` as you expect, but rather it truncates to an integer, so you get `2`.

To correct this, cast one of the integer values to a double before performing the division, like: `(diameterOld/2.0)`

Comment: Thanks man, I feel so stupid missing something so simple haha. Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to close the question by selecting an answer

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer division with 4 times with `diameterOld` (twice) and `diameterNew` (twice), which in Java results in another integer.  Even if the mathematical result is `2.5`, Java will truncate it to `2` (an `int`).

Change to divide by `double` literals to force floating-point math from the start, e.g.:

```
diameterOld/2.0
```

and likewise for the other divisions like that one.

Additionally, you are dividing `totalSurfaceArea` by `areaNew`, both of which divide the diameter by `2` and multiply by pi.  Mathematically, those cancel out in the division, so you don't even need to bother with the division by `2` or the multiplication by pi.

```
areaOld = diameterOld * diameterOld;
```

and

```
areaNew = diameterNew * diameterNew;
```

This holds mathematically when calculating `quantityNew`.

Output:

```
Mohammad's java Pancakes
Diameter of original pancakes (inches): 5
Quantity of original pancakes: 10
Diameter of new pancakes (inches): 10
Quantity of new pancakes: 2.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it is much appreciated. I was thinking that the pi's and the (/2)'s would cancel out but I just codded it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You code for area old should be

```
areaOld = (((double)(diameterOld/2))*((double)(diameterOld/2))*Math.PI);
areaNew = (((double)(diameterNew/2))*((double)(diameterNew/2))*Math.PI);
```

Comment: I don't believe so. You have to do the typecast before dividing.

Comment: @TylerGaona the problem is he is doing an int by in with will implicitly return n int ... so we need to cast it to double.

Comment: Casting to a double after the fact won't give the expected result. It needs to be done before the division